# on other window tab active call a function

Tags: jquery

I have a slider button and it is toggling as per click events. I have a question on this when I click to other tab of the window I want to call a function which will hide that  slider previously opened. How to call a function if current tab of the window is not active?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Page Visibility API](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/).

For more information, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060034/1319187) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1060008/1319187).